# how to implement glob.glob

Tags: python, search, pygtk, glob, os.walk

currently my os.walk code list's all the files in all directories under the specified directory.

```
top = /home/bludiescript/tv-shows
        for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(top):
               for filename in filenames:
                  print os.path.join([dirname, filename])
```

so how could i add

```
glob.glob(search)
search = self.search.get_text
```

to search for the pattern that i type in the gtk.Entry

or is this something that would not work with my current code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want `glob.glob` for this; it checks against names in the directory, which you've already retrieved. Instead, use `fnmatch.fnmatch` to match your pattern against the list of pathnames you got from `os.walk` (probably before you add the path).

```
for filename in filenames:
    if fnmatch.fnmatch(filename, search):
        print os.path.join([dirname, filename])
```

Comment: thanx for the in put and the knowledge so to be clear the glob function only checks the pattern for directories already found ie current directories?

Comment: its not showing any errors but its also not printing anything does fnmatch need the whole file name or can it use parts of a file name like a single word ?

Answer (score 4):

You don't want `glob`, you want `fnmatch`.

```
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(top):
    for filename in filenames:
        if fnmatch.fnmatch(filename, my_pattern):
            print os.path.join([dirname, filename])
```

`glob` does part of the work that `os.walk` has already done: examine the disk to find files.  `fnmatch` is a pure string operation: does this filename match this pattern?

Comment: thanx for your knowledge on this it was helpful in my learning of python

Comment: i looked on docs.python on the top it listed the patterns *, ?, [seq], and [!seq] each doing different things. now i tried if fnmatch.fnmatch(filename, [search]) it gave an unhashable 'list' error

Comment: fnmatch takes two strings, not a string and a list.